# I don't get this no matter how many times i recode its still the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
import tkinter as tk


class Calculator:
def __init__(self):

    self.window = tk.Tk()
    self.window.geometry("375*667")
    self.window.resizable(0,0)
    self.window.title("Calculator")


def run(self):
    self.window.mainloop()
```

this the code I have been working

And Here is The Problem I Have been Facing

```
 File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\calculator\calc.py", line 5
    def __init__(self):
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after class definition on line 4
```

Comment: Well, without any context **and** without a screenshot (which you shouldn't do in the first place, we can't copy code from screenshots) we cannot help you of course.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).   (Even if you can figure out how to do it correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all your code from line 5 to 10 and press TAB. Your indentation is wrong, just as your error message says it is.

Comment: oh Thanks When i click on tab it worked but a new error showed up

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "375*667"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       This Is The new error

Comment: Well that is a whole other issue then, can't help without any context. It seems you are trying to do something invalid in the tkinter library, I have no idea what you are trying to do of course without your code.

Comment: no need to help again bro i figured it myself anyway thanks again

Comment: well if you please help me with this https://serverfault.com/questions/1103577/pycharm-run-not-showing-i-have-been-facing-this-issue-for-no-matter-what-i-do-i